# Glossaries: Print acronyms with indentation

Tags: indentation, glossaries, acronyms

hey there,
when I print the glossary of the package 'glossaries' like that:

`\printglossary[type=\acronymtype] % acronyms`

I get something without indentation:

```
A aaaskjdh
BADR alksjd blaa
FO text text
```

But I want something like that:

```
A    aaaskjdh
BADR alksjd blaa
FO   text text
```

I tried `style=long4col` and `style=long` but that prints out the acronysm non-bold and there's some sort of indentation in front of the acronym itself:

```
   A    aaaskjdh
   BADR alksjd blaa
   FO   text text
```

I really JUST want the plain style with indentation ONLY between the acronym and the description. ANy way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Same question in the German community MrUnix:
http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=71228

Comment: Thanks, but there's not really an answer to it!

Comment: But for all users it is easier to know this.

Answer (score 7):

I missing a minimal working example. Why don't you provide one? The most of your explanation is useless and a minimal example says more than 100 lines of any explanation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-longragged} 
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}
\newacronym{A}{A}{blabla}
\newacronym{BASD}{BASD}{alskdj}
\newacronym{OAJ}{OAJ}{kjoasd}
\newglossarystyle{super3colleft}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\tablehead{}\tabletail{}%
     \begin{supertabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}lp{\glsdescwidth}p{\glspagelistwidth}}}%
    {\end{supertabular}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3 & ##5\\}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
     &
     \glssubentryitem{##2}%
     \glstarget{##2}{\strut}##4 & ##6\\}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{ & &\\}%
}

\newlength{\acronymlabelwidth}
\setlength{\acronymlabelwidth}{0.25\textwidth}
\newglossarystyle{listwithwidth}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{description}}{\end{description}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \item[\parbox{\acronymlabelwidth}{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}}]
       ##3\glspostdescription\space ##5}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
    \glssubentryitem{##2}%
    \glstarget{##2}{\strut}##4\glspostdescription\space ##6.}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\indexspace}%
}
\begin{document}
Die Ausgabe im Text: \gls{A}\qquad\gls{BASD}\qquad\gls{OAJ}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=super3colleft]

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=listwithwidth]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really didn't know what to do a minimal example for, it's such an 'easy' problem to understand and it was perfectly explained, just read it twice to see if something was missing. And as I see, you answered it nearly perfectly! I want to use the second style with just a little change which I can't do myself: as you can see here: http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/9389/zwischenablage02we.jpg I would like the margin between the groups of acronyms to be a little bit bigger (different first characters) and the margin between two lines within one group a little bit smaller. Possible?

Comment: @Marc: By group, you mean all acronyms starting with the same letter? Because there is a difference in Marco's example, the space between two acronyms starting with e.g. A is a little smaller than between one starting with A and one with B.

Comment: "By group, you mean all acronyms starting with the same letter? " Yes thats correct.

Comment: I fixed it myself by setting the line `\begin{supertabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}lp{\glsdescwidth}p{\glspagelistwidth}}}%` to `\begin{supertabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}lp{1.5\glsdescwidth}p{\glspagelistwidth}}}%` in the super3colleft style!